# Parsing a chemical formula from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, chemistry

I am trying to parse a chemical formula (in the format, for example: `Al2O3` or `O3` or `C` or `C11H22O12`) in C# from a string. It works fine unless there is only one atom of a particular element (e.g. the oxygen atom in `H2O`). How can I fix that problem, and in addition, is there a better way to parse a chemical formula string than I am doing?

ChemicalElement is a class representing a chemical element. It has properties AtomicNumber (int), Name (string), Symbol (string).
ChemicalFormulaComponent is a class representing a chemical element and atom count (e.g. part of a formula). It has properties Element (ChemicalElement), AtomCount (int).

The rest should be clear enough to understand (I hope) but please let me know with a comment if I can clarify anything, before you answer.

Here is my current code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Parses a chemical formula from a string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="chemicalFormula">The string to parse.</param>
    /// <exception cref="FormatException">The chemical formula was in an invalid format.</exception>
    public static Collection<ChemicalFormulaComponent> FormulaFromString(string chemicalFormula)
    {
        Collection<ChemicalFormulaComponent> formula = new Collection<ChemicalFormulaComponent>();

        string nameBuffer = string.Empty;
        int countBuffer = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < chemicalFormula.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = chemicalFormula[i];

            if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || !char.IsUpper(chemicalFormula, 0))
            {
                throw new FormatException("Input string was in an incorrect format.");
            }
            else if (char.IsUpper(c))
            {
                // Add the chemical element and its atom count
                if (countBuffer > 0)
                {
                    formula.Add(new ChemicalFormulaComponent(ChemicalElement.ElementFromSymbol(nameBuffer), countBuffer));

                    // Reset
                    nameBuffer = string.Empty;
                    countBuffer = 0;
                }

                nameBuffer += c;
            }
            else if (char.IsLower(c))
            {
                nameBuffer += c;
            }
            else if (char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                if (countBuffer == 0)
                {
                    countBuffer = c - '0';
                }
                else
                {
                    countBuffer = (countBuffer * 10) + (c - '0');
                }
            }
        }

        return formula;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you checking whether the first character of the formula is upper case on every iteration of the `for` loop (`!char.IsUpper(chemicalFormula, 0)`)? The index here is always `0`.

Comment: I think your function also has problem with something like C4O2 is this true?

Comment: See also the page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974362/parsing-a-chemical-formula/3742985 . It asks for one in Java, with an answer in Python, and links to more complex ANTLR and Python solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing a chemical formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974362/parsing-a-chemical-formula)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I rewrote your parser using regular expressions. Regular expressions fit the bill perfectly for what you're doing. Hope this helps.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var testCases = new List<string>
    {
        "C11H22O12",
        "Al2O3",
        "O3",
        "C",
        "H2O"
    };

    foreach (string testCase in testCases)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing {0}", testCase);

        var formula = FormulaFromString(testCase);

        foreach (var element in formula)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", element.Element, element.Count);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    /* Produced the following output

    Testing C11H22O12
    C : 11
    H : 22
    O : 12

    Testing Al2O3
    Al : 2
    O : 3

    Testing O3
    O : 3

    Testing C
    C : 1

    Testing H2O
    H : 2
    O : 1
        */
}

private static Collection<ChemicalFormulaComponent> FormulaFromString(string chemicalFormula)
{
    Collection<ChemicalFormulaComponent> formula = new Collection<ChemicalFormulaComponent>();
    string elementRegex = "([A-Z][a-z]*)([0-9]*)";
    string validateRegex = "^(" + elementRegex + ")+$";

    if (!Regex.IsMatch(chemicalFormula, validateRegex))
        throw new FormatException("Input string was in an incorrect format.");

    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(chemicalFormula, elementRegex))
    {
        string name = match.Groups[1].Value;

        int count =
            match.Groups[2].Value != "" ?
            int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value) :
            1;

        formula.Add(new ChemicalFormulaComponent(ChemicalElement.ElementFromSymbol(name), count));
    }

    return formula;
}
```

Comment: This looks perfect, thanks so much. Sidenote though - shouldn't the * near [A-Z][a-z] be a +?

Comment: The `*` only applies to one `[]` group. This means that the `[A-Z]` must appear exactly once (because it doesn't have a `*` or an `+`), and the `[a-z]` must appear zero or more times.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Not reading my parenthesis correctly. Thanks again!

Comment: The second group should be made optional (i.e. "([A-Z][a-z]*)([0-9]+)?") so you can do int count = match.Groups[2].Success ? a : b; instead of the .Value != "". Addtionally, it should be a + in the second group since you want to match 1 or more number characters.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your method is here:

```
            // Add the chemical element and its atom count
            if (countBuffer > 0)
```

When you don't have a number, count buffer will be 0, I think this will work

```
            // Add the chemical element and its atom count
            if (countBuffer > 0 || nameBuffer != String.Empty)
```

This will work when for formulas like HO2 or something like that.
I believe that your method will never insert into the `formula` collection the las element of the chemical formula.

You should add the last element of the bufer to the collection before return the result, like this:

```
    formula.Add(new ChemicalFormulaComponent(ChemicalElement.ElementFromSymbol(nameBuffer), countBuffer));

    return formula;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all: I haven't used a parser generator in .net, but I'm pretty sure you could find something appropriate. This would allow you to write the grammar of Chemical Formulas in a far more readable form. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153572/parser-generator-that-outputs-c-given-a-bnf-grammar) for a first start.

If you want to keep your approach: Is it possible that you do not add your last element no matter if it has a number or not? You might want to run your loop with `i<= chemicalFormula.Length` and in case of `i==chemicalFormula.Length` also add what you have to your Formula. You then also have to remove your `if (countBuffer > 0)` condition because countBuffer can actually be zero!

Answer (score 0):

Regex should work fine with simple formula, if you want to split something like:

```
(Zn2(Ca(BrO4))K(Pb)2Rb)3
```

it might be easier to use the parser for it (because of compound nesting). Any parser should be capable of handling it.

I spotted this problem few days ago I thought it would be good example how one can write grammar for a parser, so I included simple chemical formula grammar into my [NLT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/naivelangtools/) suite. The **key** rules are -- for lexer:

```
"(" -> LPAREN;
")" -> RPAREN;

/[0-9]+/ -> NUM, Convert.ToInt32($text);
/[A-Z][a-z]*/ -> ATOM;
```

and for parser:

```
comp -> e:elem { e };

elem -> LPAREN e:elem RPAREN n:NUM? { new Element(e,$(n : 1)) }
      | e:elem++ { new Element(e,1) }
      | a:ATOM n:NUM? { new Element(a,$(n : 1)) }
      ;
```