# Produce Delphi Code that will Parse a file with a given BNF format

Tags: delphi, parsing, code-generation, bnf, gedcom

Is there parser code or a parser component for Delphi or a program that will accept BNF (Backus-Naur Form) notation as input and produce Delphi (or pascal) code to do the parsing?

The reason for this is that I am going to be attempting to perfectly parse data sets following various versions of [the GEDCOM standard](http://phpgedview.sourceforge.net/ged551-5.pdf) (used for genealogy), and will need to process the file from state to state as tokens are reached. I would prefer an automated program to do the grunt work of setting up the basic pascal code to do the state to state processing for me.

Otherwise, I'll have to manually build the state structures myself.

I did see the following question (and [TinyPG](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28294/a-Tiny-Parser-Generator-v1-2) looks good, but I need Delphi code):
[Parser-generator that outputs C# given a BNF grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153572/parser-generator-that-outputs-c-sharp-given-a-bnf-grammar)

If there isn't such a beast, are there any other tools available that will make this task easier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you the [GOLD](http://goldparser.org/) parsing system. GOLD grammars are based on Backus-Naur form and regular expressions.

**Resources**

- [gold-parser](/questions/tagged/gold-parser)
- [Wikipedia entry page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOLD_(parser))
- [Yahoo group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/GOLDParser/)

**Engines**

Engines for Delphi are particularly listed [here](http://goldparser.org/engine/1/delphi/index.htm).

This [one](http://goldparser.org/engine/1/pascal/van-den-brink-PasEngine_v11.zip) for Object Pascal by *Rob van den Brink* might be of interest.

Quote:

> Rob van den Brink updated his engine for the Object Pascal Programming
>   Language. His implementation uses a program template to create a
>   full-functioning program. This approach embeds the parse tables
>   directly in the source code. As a result, you do not need to load a
>   Compiled Grammar Table file. The download contains a program template
>   as well as several examples.

**Sample project using GOLD**

GOLD is powerfull, it is used as the parsing engine of [dcu2pas](http://dcu2pas.dmon.com/), a Delphi Compiled Unit (dcu files) decompiler which is hosted [here](https://bitbucket.org/soarowl/dcu2pas/overview) (bitbucket.org). Notice instead that it's written in [d](/questions/tagged/d).

Comment: I really like the GOLD parsing system, especially the editor and debugger. Unfortunately the Delphi engine implementation is a decade old, the Readme.txt for `Rob van den Brink`'s code says "24 April 2002". It predates Delphi Unicode by a good 7 years.

Comment: Yes, they are aging but can be improved. Recent C# engine implementations are using bleeding edge construct. Matthias Piepkorn's D (Digital Mars D) engine is inspired by those Delphi engines and I find it really excellent. It's high time the Delphi community take back the best of it and get down to keep up.

Comment: This looks like exactly the tool I was hoping to find. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @Cosmin, I have revamped a more recent Delphi implementation for GOLD and may publish it when it is adjusted to V5.

Comment: @UweRaabe, that would be grate.